# what is the right way to use CLEAN rake task?

Tags: ruby, rake, rake-task

This is what I'm trying to do in my Rakefile:

```
require 'rake/clean'
CLEAN = ['coverage']
```

This is what I see in the log:

```
$ rake
/code/foo/Rakefile:29: warning: already initialized constant CLEAN
/Users/foo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/clean.rb:61: warning: previous definition of CLEAN was here
```

I don't like these warnings.. What is the right way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`'rake/clean'` already defines the constant `CLEAN` like so: `CLEAN = ::Rake::FileList["**/*~", "**/*.bak", "**/core"]`. Constants aren't meant to be overridden (although ruby will let you). If you want to specify the files to be cleaned, you should create your own rake task similar the existing one.

The existing task runs:

```
Rake::Cleaner.cleanup_files(CLEAN)
```

So you could run:

```
Rake::Cleaner.cleanup_files(['coverage'])
```

to clean up your coverage files.

Comment: if `coverage` is a directory and you want to cleanup everything in it you can also pass `Rake::Cleaner.cleanup_files` a `FileList`: `Rake::Cleaner.cleanup_files(FileList['coverage/**/*'])`

Answer (score 13):

`CLEAN` is a [`FileList`](http://docs.seattlerb.org/rake/Rake/FileList.html) that is used by the predefined `clean` task. To add your own files to be cleaned, add them to this list. You can use the `include` method:

```
require 'rake/clean'
CLEAN.include 'coverage'
```

Now running `rake clean` will remove your files, as well as the predefined set of temporary files if any have bean created.

Comment: Much nicer than the accepted answer IMHO. This lets you use the predefined `clean` task to remove your generated files.

Comment: Another way of adding things to `CLEAN` is `CLEAN << 'coverage'`